# How do i navigate from one Xaml file to another?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to XAML and WPF.I have a problem.

I have two files. first.xaml and second.Xaml. There is a button in first.xaml, on click of which it should navigate to second.xaml.How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of organising the code:

Your `second.xaml` should contain your window definiton e.g.:

```
<Window x:Class="MediaCheckerWPF.AboutBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="About Media Checker" Height="300" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Icon="/MediaCheckerWPF;component/Resources/checker.ico"
    ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Your `first.xaml` has the button e.g.:

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="aboutButton"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Click="AboutButton_Click"
 Content="{DynamicResource TInformationButton}"
 ToolTip="{DynamicResource TInformationButtonTooltip}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
private void AboutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var about = new AboutBox { Owner = this };
    about.Initialise();
    about.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ChrisF's answer is a good way of popping up a new window in a Windows-style application, except you should not call Initialize that way (it should be called from the constructor).

If you want web-style navigation instead, you should use the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.aspx) class instead of Window, along with [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx).  This also allows your WPF application to run inside an actual web browser.