# Why my xaml only shows a plain window show up with nothig in it

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am new to WPF, Xaml, and am a C# beginner! I have been working on this and I don't know why the following xaml just shows a plain window. No button, no title, no content. I would appreciate your guidance.  If asking why I had to use MediaChecker I did it following an example from Stack Overflow's following post:

[How do i navigate from one Xaml file to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834028/how-do-i-navigate-from-one-xaml-file-to-another)

Thanks in advance.

```
<Window x:Class="MediaCheckerWPF.AboutBox" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="About Media Checker" Height="300" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="E-Mail:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Comment:"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Content="START"  />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Content="STOP"  />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The XAML you have renders just fine. If you're getting a blank window then I suspect it has to do with something else, such as not starting up the correct Window.

Comment: Rachel; thanks your answer helped , the problem was: not starting up the correct window.  However, I can't find a way to vote for your help. I guess you have to select answer and then I can give my feedback.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that helped you out :) I expanded my comment in an answer below for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML you have renders just fine. If you're getting a blank window then I suspect it has to do with something else, such as starting up a different Window.

Double-check that the correct `Window` is starting up in the [StartupUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri.aspx) property of your `<Application>` tag in `App.xaml`

```
<Application x:Class="MediaCheckerWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="AboutBox.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the App.xaml for the StartupUri

```
<Application x:Class="GabeTexFilestImport.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this happening also if system is very slow.  Say, you are reaching max memory consumption which slows down your system.  In that case, I have seen xaml windows showing up but completelly blank, no controls on it, no min, max, close buttons, no title.