# Main Window shows no content

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am a beginner in C# and I am following [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-the-net-desktop-application/)

That tutorial uses Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and SQL Server Management Studio.

Instead of using SQL Server 2008 Express edition, like in tutorial, I am using SQL Server 2017 Express.

So, my solution contains 6 projects (one WPF and 5 class libraries - all of them using .Net Framework).

I have set `EmployeeFrontEndApp` as the startup project.

This is the code from my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="EmployeeFrontEndApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmployeeFrontEndApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:EmployeeDetails />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the code from my EmployeeDetails.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="EmployeeFrontEndApp.EmployeeDetails"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmployeeFrontEndApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:EmployeeDetailsVM />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="Header1" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Header1}">Employee Details</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1"></Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="2">Employee ID:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding Employee.Employee_ID}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3">Employee Name:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding Employee.Employee_Name}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="4">Age:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding Employee.Age}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="5">Address:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding Employee.Address}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="6">Date of Joining:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding Employee.Date_Joining, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyy'}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="7">Date of Joining:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding Employee.Date_Leaving, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyy'}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I also have a EmployeeDetailsVM.cs file in this project:

```
using System.Linq;
using EmployeeBL;

namespace EmployeeFrontEndApp
{
    public class EmployeeDetailsVM : ObservableObject
    {
        private EmployeeUI.Employee _employee;

        public EmployeeUI.Employee Employee
        {
            get => _employee;
            set
            {
                _employee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
            }
        }

        public EmployeeDetailsVM()
        {
            IEmployeeBL EmployeeBL = new EmployeeBL.EmployeeBL(new EmployeeDAL.EmployeeDAL());
            Employee = EmployeeBL.GetAllEmployees().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know what other code to post here, because I don't want to post the entire project.

Each time I run my project I get this:

[image]

BUT in the tutorial the app looks like this

[image]

I know that the database connection is working because in my EmployeeDetails.xaml file (from `EmployeeFrontEndApp`) it shows me the data from my database:

[image]

Because I am a beginner in C# and Visual Studio, I am asking you kindly to answer this: what could prevent my application from being displayed properly and where in my code should I look to offer you more clear details about this issue?

Edit: Today I found this post [Why my xaml only shows a plain window show up with nothig in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148097/why-my-xaml-only-shows-a-plain-window-show-up-with-nothig-in-it)
and I changed my App.xaml file
this line of code `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` to this `StartupUri="EmployeeDetails.xaml"`

and now this shows up:
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAXAX.png)

I am not sure this is the right solution, because in this image "Main Window" text is missing AND my MainWindow.xaml file becomes totaly useless.
How can I keep the application working and keep using MainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your EmployeeDetails.xaml control is being added to your MainWindow.xaml window. This is unlikely to be a database issue. It's more likely that your control is never being added to the window to begin with.

Comment: Hello Mr! I just added in my original post an image with the content of MainWindows.xaml. It is added, through "<local:EmployeeDetails />". Where should I look next?

Comment: Hmm OK. Then I think to investigate this further please update your post with more code relevant to what isn't working.

Comment: I updated it now. I posted the content from my WFP project "EmployeeFrontEndApp".  Is it enough to see what goes wrong?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out. How can I access my application through MainWindows not through EmployeeDetails?